# Install postgres extension PGXN "fatal error: unistd.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions

I need to sync some postgres tables with elasticsearch and come to conclusion that the best solution for my case is the one described [here](http://www.codedependant.net/2020/03/27/heard-of-rabbits-1-postgres-change-data-capture-and-rabbitmq/). Unfortunately I'm still failing to install required postgres extension [amqp](https://pgxn.org/dist/pg_amqp/doc/amqp.html).

I use docker so I start from image [postgres:13-alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres).

Here is how my Dockerfile looks like so far:

```
FROM postgres:13-alpine

ENV POSTGRES_DB ''
ENV POSTGRES_USER ''
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD ''

RUN apk update \
  && apk add py-pip make gcc \
  && pip install pgxnclient
```

Then when you enter the container and try to run `pgxn install pg_amqp` you will get following error.

```
bash-5.1# pgxn install pg_amqp
INFO: best version: pg_amqp 0.3.0
INFO: saving /tmp/tmpgjtefhgh/pg_amqp-0.3.0.zip
INFO: unpacking: /tmp/tmpgjtefhgh/pg_amqp-0.3.0.zip
INFO: building extension
gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Werror=vla -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-stringop-truncation -O2 -fPIC -I. -I./ -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/internal  -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o src/pg_amqp.o src/pg_amqp.c
src/pg_amqp.c:36:10: fatal error: unistd.h: No such file or directory
   36 | #include <unistd.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: src/pg_amqp.o] Error 1
ERROR: command returned 2: make PG_CONFIG=/usr/local/bin/pg_config all
```

It seems that I am out of the ideas what to do with that. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the musl C library (libc) implementation: `musl-dev`

```
RUN apk update \
  && apk add py-pip make gcc musl-dev \
  && pip install pgxnclient
```